# Functions are not valid as a React child -- When building a PrivateRoute Component React ver 16

Tags: reactjs, react-router, higher-order-components

Hi there I have built a ProtectedRoute component and I wish to include it in my App component. While I see it work for many others, I'm not sure why Im the odd one out. Code Below:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, path, ...rest }) => {
 return (<Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
    firebaseApp.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        if (user) {
            <Component {...props} />;
        } else {
            <Redirect
                to={{
                    pathname: "/",
                    state: {
                        prevLocation: path,
                        error: "You need to login first!",
                    },
                }}
            />
          }
       })
     )} />
   )
}

class App extends Component {
 displayName = App.name

 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
 }

 render() {

    return (
        <Layout>
            <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
            <Route path='/signin' component={SignIn} />
            <Route path='/signup' component={SignUp} />
            <PrivateRoute path='/counter' component={Counter} /> 
            <Route path='/fetchdata' component={FetchData} />
        </Layout>
    );
 }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

The Routes render method is returning a function which it shouldn't

```
firebaseApp.auth().onAuthStateChanged
```

In your case you should use a React component and not a functional component.

```
const withAuth = (Component) => {
    class AuthComp extends React.Component {
       state={
           loading: true,
           user: null
       }
       componentDidMount() {
         firebaseApp.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
                this.setState({loading: false, user})
         });
       }
       render() {
           if(loading) {
               return <div>Loading...</div>
           }
           if(!loading && !user) {
             return <Redirect
                    to={{
                        pathname: "/",
                        state: {
                            prevLocation: path,
                            error: "You need to login first!",
                        },
                    }}
                />
           }
           return <Component {this.props} />

       }
    }
}


const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, path, ...rest }) => {
   return (<Route {...rest} component={withAuth(Component)} />)
}
```

Comment: I implemented your response (with the right state props ref) and the error disappears but the page is not redirecting. Can you shed light on that?

Comment: Did you import Redirect and also use it like `<Route {...rest} component={withAuth(Component)} />`

Comment: I have <Route path='/counter' component={withAuth(Counter)}  />

Comment: or should it be <PrivateRoute path='/counter' component={withAuth(Counter)}  />

Comment: You could simple use `<Route path='/counter' component={withAuth(Counter)} />`

Comment: I added that with a console.log() to see if the AuthComp component was touched and there was no response from console.log